# Are EcmaScript and JavaScript referring to the same language?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that there is JavaScript and also there is EcmaScript. When I started studying web development started with HTML then CSS then PHP then JavaScript, but all throughout I used vanilla versions or the plain language itself without any external libraries and frameworks (except for PHP which is technically composed of libraries, I believe),

then I learned about frameworks and started studying frameworks such as `JQuery` which is a javascript library (right?), then I started studying `ReactJS` and learned that I have to use EcmaScript but I can't hardly differentiate the two because they seem to be the same thing but people told me that JavaScript doesn't have features of EcmaScript such as `classes`, `import`, `export`, `arrow functions`, `let`, etc, but they appear to be the same thing.

Then I read the book Eloquent JavaScript, which stated that EcmaScript and JavaScript are two names for the same language and therefore they refer to the same language.

So what is true and what is false?

Comment: [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf)

Comment: for all practical purposes, EcmaScript === JavaScript.

Comment: it's like "Kleenex" vs "Facial Tissue"; JS is one "brand" of ES, technically owned by Oracle. "ActionScript" and "JScript" are other branding examples. To be pedantic, only firefox runs "JavaScript", but in common use it's all a rose by another name.

Comment: JavaScript had those most of those features long before ECMAScript did, since FireFox's JS is "JavaScript(tm)", and the moz features guided ES6.

Comment: @dandavis your phrase in your first comment is ambiguous: someone can think that ES is owned by Oracle. However, the *European Computer Manufacturers Association* is not owned by Oracle, but the "JavaScript" name, which is a trademark of Oracle. To avoid ambiguity: "JS is one 'brand' of ES and it's technically owned by Oracle".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: ECMAScript=="FacialTissue" in my example, you're right that could have been clearer...

Comment: please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and Ecmascript are the same language which we type but the story of the name javascript some say it comes from that java was very popular back then so it was kind of a marketing plan but as far as we are concerned js 2015 is ecmascript 6 so javascript is Ecmascript

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag info:

> **[ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)** was developed as a standardization of Netscape's [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and Microsoft's independently-developed [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0.aspx). The canonical reference is the [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). While JavaScript and JScript aim to be compatible with ECMAScript, they also provide additional features (and [other deviations](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=resources:resources&cache=cache&media=resources:jscriptdeviationsfromes3.pdf)) not described in the ECMA specifications. [Other implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Dialects) of ECMAScript also exist.
>
> The differences today for those who use JavaScript are negligible; people generally do not distinguish the JavaScript and JScript variations from ECMAScript.

Comment: so in short they are all refering to the same language but different features, and that the language's engine (like V8) supports all (or most) of these features?